# Find most occurring records.

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Suppose there are 3 fields in a mysql table: id, word and date.
The word field is not a unique field, so many records have the same word.
So how do I find out which word is repeated in records the most, exactly? The most repeated 5 words..

Comment: What do you mean by "most occurring 5 records", the newest created records?

Comment: In one field the data is not unique.. and how to find the most number of records that has the same value.

Comment: If it can't be done in one field then you just :group by multiple fields until you have whatever fields deems two records to be "identical".

Answer (score 1):

```
Model.find(:all, :conditions => ["created_at > ?", DateTime.now - 2.hours], :limit => 5, :order => "desc")
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the answers above seem to print just the most recent record.  I think to get the most frequent you will need to use more SQL. :-(

Assuming you have a model called Message with a field called 'text' which contains the messages...

```
Message.find(:all, :select => '*, COUNT(*) AS count',
                   :group  => 'text',
                   :order  => 'count DESC',
                   :limit  => 5 )
```

Disclaimer: I have never tried doing this, except to verify that the code itself runs.

Comment: One would assume the 5 which occur the most.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  named_scope :recent, :conditions => ["created_at > ?", DateTime.now - 2.hours], :limit => 5, :order => "desc"

end

Model.recent
```